# Bookshelf.JS: Related Model is trying to be used before being required

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have two models that are related, Customers and Addresses. I first discovered this issue when I was trying to create a customer with a related address. For our purposes, a single customer can have multiple addresses, and when creating a new customer, we want to create an address at the same time as we create the customer.

I did some digging through the documentation and set up the relationship as best as I could, and this seemed to work well enough, but then I noticed that when I included both the models in modules together, (i.e. my routes/controllers), I was getting circular references.

Long story short, my research lead me to add the `registry` plugin to my `bookshelf.js` file. This worked at the time, but now it looks like my `Address` model isn't properly exported when being referenced in Customers.

Here's a snippet of my current configuration

```
// bookshelf.js
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin([
  'registry',
]);
module.exports = bookshelf;


// customers.js
const bookshelf = require('../bookshelf');
const Address = require('./address');

const Customer = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'customers',
  addresses: function () {
    return this.hasMany('Address');
  },
}, {
  customCreate: function (attributes) {
    return this.forge(attributes)
      .save()
      .tap(c => {
        return Address.forge(attributes)
          .save({
            customer_id: c.get('id'),
          });
      })
  }
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model('Customer', Customer);


// address.js
const bookshelf = require('../bookshelf');
const Customer = require('./customer');

const Address = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'addresses',
  customer: function () {
    return this.belongsTo('Customer');
  }
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model('Address', Address);
```

I started to notice that when I would run `Customer.customCreate()`, I got an error saying `Address.forge is not a function`. I threw some console logs into my `customer.js` file and saw that `Address` is an empty object (`{}`) when being referenced within `customer.js`. However, in other places, it's returning the proper Bookshelf model.

Looks to me like I'm trying to use my Address model in customers before it's properly required, which made me wonder if I'm structuring my project and models properly, or if there's any changes I need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a circular reference problem alright. The best way to structure your models so that there are no such problems is to load them all during your app's initialization in a single file, e.g. `index.js` on your models' directory, attach each one to an object and export that object. Then you just `require()` that file and get access to all the models in a single place.

However, to solve your problem in a much easier way you just need to make a single change to your `customCreate()` method:

```
customCreate: function (attributes) {
  return this.forge(attributes)
    .save()
    .tap(c => this.related('addresses').create(attributes))
  }
}
```

This makes use of the [`Collection.create`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-create) method to easily create a new model inside a collection, and since it's used on a relation it will also set the correct foreign key.

Note that the Registry plugin will not save you from circular dependency problems, but it will allow you to write your models in a way that *avoids* them.

Comment: So I remember trying something like this five different ways before throwing up my hands in frustration, with no success. Thanks for giving me some clarity.

Comment: On a side note, could you give me an example of how you recommend loading these files?

Comment: Sure, [here's an example gist](https://gist.github.com/ricardograca/31dfebb71f8147fa40ec5cb2175b86c0). You can also add your plugins and other customizations in this file.